# MySql get latest 10 records records using offset & limit?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a `article` table & I want to get the latest articles (10 of them) & then also be able to make another call to get the next 10 latest articles (10-20). To give you an idea to why I want to be able to do this, it's so I can add a `nextUrl` field to my `API` call.

I was hoping I'd be able to use `offset & limit` to achieve this. But it seems as though I can only do this from the records that were entered first. Any ideas?

Comment: do you want pagination in web-service?

Comment: @PathikVejani Yeah pretty much. Which is why I need to add a limit & offset!

Answer (score 0):

For example, try this pagination in web-service:

```
<?php
$perpage = '10';
$total_records = '50'; // so there will be 5 pages (50/10 = 5)
$page = "1";

function test($perpage,$page) {
    if($page == '') {
        $page = 1;
    }
    if($page == 1)
    {
        $start = 0;
        $end = $perpage ;
    }
    else
    {
        $page -= 1;
        $start = $page * $perpage;
        $end = $perpage;
    }
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $end");
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result_array();
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
?>
```

This is in **CodeIgniter framework**.

Each time send page number. 

First time it will be 1, then second time 2, and so on.. It will give 10 records per page.